# Change the way CC-mode font-lock the C++11 `auto` syntax

Tags: font-lock, c++, cc-mode

With C++11, the keyword `auto` attained a new syntax and semantics.  However, it seems that CC-mode has not been aware of this.

For example, if I write `auto var = exp`, I get `var` in green, in which various types are displayed.  I don't like this; `var` should look like other variables.

How can I teach CC-mode to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to add "auto" to extra types recognized by `c++-mode`:

```
(require 'cc-mode)
(add-to-list 'c++-font-lock-extra-types "auto")
```

The downside is that now it is not highlighted as a keyword any more. (But "auto" is both a type and a keyword, in a way.)

Comment: I actually wanted `auto` to be highlighted as a type, so it is not a downside :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the package : ["Modern C++" font-lock for Emacs](https://github.com/ludwigpacifici/modern-cpp-font-lock). It is also available on [Melpa](http://melpa.org/#/modern-cpp-font-lock).

> Syntax highlighting support for "Modern C++" - until C++17 and
>   Technical Specification. This package aims to provide a simple
>   highlight of the C++ language without dependency.
>
> It is recommended to use it in addition with the c++-mode major mode
>   for extra highlighting (user defined types, functions, etc.) and
>   indentation.

I am the maintainer of this minor mode. Any feedback is appreciated.