# How to highlight “constexpr” in cc-mode?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cc-mode

**Question**

Pretty straightforward: How to highlight `constexpr` in cc-mode (editing C++ code)?

**Example**

If I use `const` as in the following example

```
const double = 3.14
```

`const` gets highlighted as a **keyword**<sup>(1)</sup> (i.e., in pink), while if I write

```
constexpr double = 3.14
```

`constexpr` gets highlighted as `all-faces` (i.e., no highlighting at all).

Ideally, a simple solution like writing

```
(add-to-keywords "constexpr") ;; pseudo-code
```

in my `.emacs` without tinkering with the code of cc-mode would be the best for me.

**Addendum**

This question might be related: [Change the way CC-mode font-lock the C++11 `auto` syntax](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/change-the-way-cc-mode-font-lock-the-c11-auto-syntax).

**Note**

<sup>(1) I *think* that it is a keyword because placing the pointer on the word and doing <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> I get: ``` Customize face (default ``font-lock-keyword-face'): ``` and pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> I get redirected to the “Easy Customization” wizard.</sup>

Comment: Related: [C++11 mode or settings for emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8549351/183120)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incantation you want is:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                        '(("constexpr" . 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

Comment: It's [dotted pair](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html#Dotted-Pair-Notation) syntax for a cons cell.  If you leave out the "." the keywords get interpreted differently.  See the help for `font-lock-keywords` for what a "non-dotted" list would mean.