# How to change syntax highlight inside #if 0?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

In `cc-mode`, I want a way set all syntax highlight colours to slightly more desaturated versions when inside a `#if 0 ... #endif` block.
If that would be troublesome/hard to maintain (having to set all the colours manually), just setting all the text inside the block to a single colour would be fine too.
I've tried [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9729/how-to-highlight-constexpr-in-cc-mode), but is intended for use with a single keyword.

I'm using `spacemacs 0.300.0@26.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs has a built-in package for ifdefs. To quote from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-C-Commands.html:

```
 ‘M-x hide-ifdef-mode’
      Hide-ifdef minor mode hides selected code within ‘#if’ and ‘#ifdef’
      preprocessor blocks.  If you change the variable
      ‘hide-ifdef-shadow’ to ‘t’, Hide-ifdef minor mode shadows
      preprocessor blocks by displaying them with a less prominent face,
      instead of hiding them entirely.  See the documentation string of
      ‘hide-ifdef-mode’ for more information.
```

Comment: I will read the doc more later, but it seems that it is what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: Can it update automatically, or do i need to call `hide-ifdefs` to update?